# How to find a data by an another data which is known?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have 1 variable called $ip that is the IP address who entered my site.
and I want to find banned states from $ip in the SQL database.

I have used this code but didnt work:

```
$state = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT bannedstate FROM `unbanned` WHERE ip=?');
$state->bind_param("b", $bannedstate);
$state->execute();
$state->bind_result($Selectedbannedstate);
$state->fetch();
```

All help will be appreciated

Comment: What you get when you print $state ?

Comment: i get nothing when i print $state

Answer (score -1):

You try to bind your $bannedstate to the parameter "b" which isn't in your statement.
I think it should be something like this

```
$state = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT bannedstate FROM `unbanned` WHERE ip=:b');
$state->bind_param(":b", $bannedstate);
$state->execute();
$state->bind_result($Selectedbannedstate);
$state->fetch();
```

Comment: Sorry but it didnt work.. :( Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you help me more?